# "IF NOT EXIST" Multiple files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want to make an IF NOT EXIST for some files like

```
IF NOT EXIST *"%input%*.jpg" && "%input%*.png"* (
ECHO.=========================================
ECHO.=  ERROR : PUT UR IMAGE FILE TO /input  =
ECHO.=========================================
pause
goto MENU
) ELSE (
ECHO.=========================================
ECHO.=             Listing  file             =
ECHO.=========================================
cd %input%
dir /B
ECHO.=========================================
ECHO.=             listing done              =
ECHO.=========================================
timeout /T 2 \> nul
cls
```

but it says

```
========================================= 
=  ERROR : PUT UR IMAGE FILE TO /input  =
=========================================
```

i already put them all png and jpg files but  i think i do somenthing wrong :O

Comment: There is no `&&` for conditionals in batch; you'll need a second `if` statement.

Comment: then how to make it scan mutiple file ?

Comment: The `if not exist *%input%*.jpg` that you already had was correct; it was just the `&&` breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if *both* files are present, I would use:

```
IF EXIST "%input%*.jpg" if exist "%input%*.png" goto :ok
echo at least one of the files is missing.
goto :eof

:ok
echo do something with both files here
```

The second `if` is only executed, when the first `if` finds the first file

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off

if exist %1\*.jpg goto :ok
if exist %1\*.png goto :ok
echo no JPG or PNG files found in %1
goto :EOF

:ok
echo found JPG and/or PNG files in %1
```

If you are looking for files in a subdirectory, you need to remember to use the directory separator (either `\` or `/`) between the directory name and the match pattern.

For testing against multiple different file types, just use multiple `if`s.

By the way, you seem to have an extra `\` there on the penultimate line, which should read: `timeout /t 2 > nul`.

Comment: nvm, i got error because if i delete only jpg without delete png it will go to error. i tried to make 2 if not command but still not reading the jpg command

Comment: ...so wait, you want to check that there are _both_ JPG and PNG files in the directory? (Because the code I exampled for you in this answer does _not_ go to error if only one of JPG or PNG are in the directory.)